# writing the x-axis label on all facets without scaling

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I want to write the x-axis on all facets but without the scale.

The output

[image]

I tried to use `scales='free_x' with scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)` but it didn't work .

```
plot2 <- ggplot(counter2, aes(x = as.character(week) , y = freq,group=Delivery.time)) +
  geom_point(colour = "red") + geom_line(colour = "red") + 
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Number Of Customers") + 
  facet_grid(.~Delivery.time) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = freq),size = 2.5, hjust = .5, vjust=-0.5) + 
  facet_wrap(~Delivery.time, ncol = 1, scales = x) + 
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

Plot with scaled x-axis

[image]

I want all a-axis

Comment: You could set the breaks and/or the limits of the scale manually

Comment: the dates here are strings it you noticed " aes(x = as.character(week) " 
how to do that ?